# Blackberry 507 Erorr

Tags: blackberry

I didn't think it would be so catastrophic when I typed

**JavaLoader -usb wipe -a**

into the command line with my blackberry 8800 test device. It reboots with a 507 error that I can't get rid of.

I have Blackberry Desktop Manager 4.6, which is normally what I use to upload my test apps, but this time I go to Application Loader, hitting start gives me that dialog box that shows me the list of 1 USB connection "PIN: xxx" with a password field (which I have no idea of,) then it says "connecting to boot ROM" then stops at the message: A connection to the device can not be established...

Now is there a hard physical way of resetting my blackberry 8800, please?

Answer (score 1):

507 is a missing COD file that is required.  Your best bet is to reload the OS.  Here's some instructions from the BlackBerry forums:
[How To Reload Your Operating System](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Device-Software/How-To-Reload-Your-Operating-System/m-p/228990)